# Why isn't AUNetSend available on iOS? (Or any alternative suggestions)

Tags: ios, audiounit

I just tried **AUNetSend** and **AUNetReceive** on two Macs using garageband. The delay was exceptionally low! I am very disappointed to find that AUNetSend is not available on iOS, however. I'm trying to stream audio from an iOS device to a receiver app on my Mac. Does anyone have any alternative suggestions as to go about doing this? Here's what I'm trying to do essentially. It must have very low latency, so GKVoiceChat won't work.

Answer (score -1):

audio+midi can be routed from and to iPad, via USB to PC/MAC, thanks to iConnectMIDI+ devices

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was trying to do it wirelessly. I've come up with an alternate solution using BSD sockets though, so it's mostly all good.